# How can I fix my master branch from older commit in git

Tags: git

In master branch I have the following commits:
master: a,b,c,d,e,f
However I made a mistake which I have to checkout from commit c and made a new branch from it

```
git checkout c
git checkout -b master2
```

master2 has the latest commits and now i want to put them to master branch without having to deal with possible conflicts. I want master branch to have all the latest commits in master2 without d,e and f commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would just to reset the master branch:

```shell
$ git reset c --hard # from the master branch itself.
```

Comment: i had to do `git push --force`

Answer (score 0):

You can do what are asking for in one step.

```
git checkout -B master c
```

`git checkout <commit>` will update the working tree to the commit specified

`-b <branch>` flag will create a new branch. But we are using `-B <branch>` (notice the uppercase `B`) which will point an existing branch to the commit specified.